# Python: Understanding unfamiliar function syntax (from UC Berkeley CS61A)

Tags: python, syntax, parameters, lambda, optional-parameters

I can't do most parts of this question without peeking at the answer key, so I figured I could ask it here. Frankly, I've always had a problem understanding functions with no parameters, and whenever I see one, I think, "OH! they must mean "print" function!" When I'm actually overcomplicating things.

As for Exercise 5, I'm not understanding how to even evaluate the expressions. I feel like it's a simple question, but I can't compute an answer to any of them.

**Exercise 4**: A Fistful of Functions

For each of the following expressions, what must f be in order for the evaluation of the expression to succeed, without causing an error? Give a definition of f for each expression such that evaluating the expression will not cause an error.

```
f
f()
f(3)
f()()
f()(3)()
```

**Solution**

```
f = 3
f = lambda: 3
f = lambda x: x
f = lambda: lambda: 3
f = lambda: lambda x: lambda: x
```

**Exercise 5**: For A Few Lambdas More

Find the value of the following three expressions, using the given values of t and s.

```
t = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(f(x)))
s = lambda x: x + 1

t(s)(0) # 1

t(t(s))(0) # 2

t(t)(s)(0) # 3
```

**Solution**

1.)   3

2.)   9

3.)   27

Comment: Walk through the execution of each line.  `t(s)(0)` means `t` is called first with `s` as the argument; the result will be a function `x + 1` that is called three times (using the result from the last call as the argument to the next call).  Then 0 is passed to that function, and the result is `((0 + 1) + 1) + 1`, which equals 3.  Try executing pieces of each expression individually, and play with the resulting functions to understand their behavior.  It isn't clear what you're looking for in terms of an answer.

Comment: "how to even evaluate the expressions" - mostly from left to right :) Substitute each function call by its result and proceed to the right. One by one.

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is here.

Comment: ok, everything makes sense now except for the last part of Exercise 5. @ChrisP, how do I evaluate t(t)(s)(0)? I got the answer "12" but not sure how... and it's wrong nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Exercise 4, you are given the following questions and answers.

Q: `f`

A: `f = 3`

This is essentially variable assignment.

Q: `f()`

A: `f = lambda: 3`

This is similar to a function that takes in no arguments and returns the value 3.

Q: `f(3)`

A: `f = lambda x: x`

This is similar to a function that takes in the argument `x` and returns the value `x`. So you are given the value `3` and a value of `3` is returned.

Q: `f()()`

A: `f = lambda: lambda: 3`

This is similar to a function that takes in no arguments and returns another function that again takes no arguments which will return the value `3`.

Q: `f()(3)()`

A: `f = lambda: lambda x: lambda: x`

Like the previous example, this will return `3`. You have function that takes in no arguments but returns another function that takes in the value `x` and returns another function that takes in no arguments but returns the value `x`.

By following the examples above, you can solve Exercise 5 in a similar fashion.

Additionally, Exercise 5 has been explained pretty well in the comments by ChrisP.